# Can Trump actually reach the steering wheel in the Beast?

Tags: donald-trump

Cassidy Hutchinson [testified](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.cbsnews.com/amp/news/trump-steering-wheel-january-6-cassidy-hutchinson-testimony-mark-meadows/) that someone told her Trump tried to grab the steering wheel of the car he was being driving in.

> When told that wouldn't be possible, Trump "reached up towards the front of the vehicle to grab at the steering wheel," she said Ornato told her.
>
> Engel then grabbed his arm and said, "Sir, you need to take your hand off the steering wheel. We're going back to the West Wing, we're not going to the Capitol," she said.
>
> In response, she said, Mr. Trump then used his free hand to lunge towards Engel, noting that when Ornato told her the story, he "motioned towards his clavicles."
>
> [...] A source close to the Secret Service confirmed to CBS News that Engel and the driver are prepared to testify under oath that neither man was physically attacked or assaulted by Trump and that the former president never lunged for the steering wheel of the vehicle.

Assuming that was the Beast, how could Trump even reach the steering wheel from the back and isn't there a partition?

Is it physically possible that the story is true?

Comment: The story says "A source close to the Secret Service" not "Trump". Frankly this Q seems a bit premature, assuming those guys are going to testify. There's a close reason here for matters under investigation.

Comment: Why is this closed?  The question is **could** he, not **did** he.  The latter is a matter of investigation, the former a matter of physics.

Answer (score 3):

For what's worth it, the presence or absence of the partition window [depends](https://leadstories.com/hoax-alert/2022/06/fact-check-suv-trump-was-riding-in-did-not-have-glass-partition-blocking-him-from-steering-wheel-on-january-6-2021.html) on which vehicle exactly was involved:

> in a June 28, 2022, interview on MSNBC, Carol Leonnig, a national investigative reporter for The Washington Post who has written the book "Zero Fail: The Rise and Fall of the Secret Service," said Trump could have gotten to the front of the vehicle [...]:
>
> > This wasn't 'the Beast.' The president was riding on January 6 in what is called 'the Suburban.' And so, this SUV, it happens to be the one the president drove in for his joy ride around Walter Reed so you'll recognize it. This is one where it would have been possible, a lot more easy, for the president to lunge forward towards the right-front seat from the back. That doesn't mean it happened. I'm just answering the question that it's a much simpler geometric issue.